# gimp 2.10 stopped working on 16.04

Tags: gimp

--RESOLVED-- with rm, reinstall ::   sudo snap install gimp --edge

gimp 2.10 worked from CLI for about a year ..

Now error appears:  gimp  or snap gimp -->

```
  /snap/gimp/227/usr/bin/gimp: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have that lib from a symlink:

```
rob@ ~$ ls -l /usr/lib32
total 1744
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   36864 Feb 23  2019 gconv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  114560 Apr 15  2016 libgcc_s.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 Oct  4 11:36 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.21
```

I do not know if `/usr/lib32` is linked when I try to run gimp from terminal

Gimp worked two days ago and I have not updated anything.

Comment: i think i need a reinstall of snap / gimp

Comment: thank you.. ubuntu 16.04 and apt-get  gimp  --> 2.8 but i can look for another repo...

Comment: thank you "gryu" the last suggestion worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try different snap channels as described [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/channels).

For example, you could use lastly updated version:

```
sudo snap install gimp --edge
```

[image: snap versions of gimp]

But be catious:

> edge: for users wanting to closely track development.
>
> Edge releases often include a moving stream of changes without QA or
>   review promises and are typically built automatically by a CI process
>   from an arbitrary source code snapshot. Often the CI will only publish
>   after some sort of automatic QA passed, and code reviews remain a good
>   practice, but these are project specific. Assume edge releases may
>   break often.

You could also try `--stable`, `--candidate`, `--beta` in the future, when they will be updated.